# Make an array of my model with an auto-increment

Tags: android

I have a Model and I want make an array of this. The problem is I do it like this :

My code :

```
final WifiModel itemsData[] = {
                new WifiModel(nearbyAccessPoints.get(0).SSID, "name"),
                new WifiModel(nearbyAccessPoints.get(1).SSID, "name"),
                new WifiModel(nearbyAccessPoints.get(2).SSID, "name"),
                new WifiModel(nearbyAccessPoints.get(3).SSID, "name"),
                new WifiModel(nearbyAccessPoints.get(4).SSID, "name"),
        };
```

And I would like to do a i++ form to i=4 for example.
How can I do that ?

My Model :

```
public class WifiModel {

    private String SSID;
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    WifiModel(String SSID, String name) {
        this.SSID = SSID;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSSID() {
        return SSID;
    }

    public void setSSID(String SSID) {
        this.SSID = SSID;
    }
}
```

Comment: Create list of model class and add in to it. when you found new ssid add in to it

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

easy :)

```
WifiModel itemsData[] = new WifiModel[5]; 
for(int i=0; i<5; i++) itemsData[i]=new WifiModel(nearbyAccessPoints.get(i).SSID, "name");
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are not for dynamic length. You can use ArrayList instead to acheive this goal as following:

```
ArrayList<WifiModel> itemsData = new ArrayList<>();

int n=4; // any number you want
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
itemData.add(new WifiModel(nearbyAccessPoints.get(i).SSID, "name"));
}
```

Comment: Nothing is mentionning this should be dynamic. If the container don't need to be update after this, the `List` is not needed. A `final WifiModel[] array` would be safe to use.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
List<WifiModel> list = new ArrayList<>();
WifiModel wifi=null;
int i;
for(i=0; i<4; i++){
    wifi = new WifiModel(nearbyAccessPoints.get(i).SSID, "name");
    list.add(wifi);
}
```